# Trying to hide submit if overdraft

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to determine if ANY table row on the page (including AJAXed content) has the class of "overdraft" and if ANY on the page does, hide a certain button. This is the code I am using but it isn't working. I don't know if the code I am using takes into account dynamic data or if it only runs at page-load.

```
(function() {
    if( $('tr').hasClass('overdraft'){ $('#btnSAMSubmit').hide(); } // end if
})();
```

Comment: Also, you might consider a linter, such as [JS Lint](http://www.jslint.com/)

Comment: You might want to consider disabling the button instead of hiding it. This keeps the layout from changing as the button appears or disappears, and a disabled button is a clearer indication of "you can't submit this form" than a missing button.

Comment: Also, without the context that this code is in, we cannot answer whether this is executed dynamically or only at page load. The `(function() {...})();` stuff is just a scope wrapper; the code inside is executed immediately in its context. BTW, usually I see this kind of encapsulation used for modules, and with jQuery users I see the form `(function($) {...})(jQuery);` which lets the wrapped code use `$` in place of `jQuery` even if `$` was redefined to something else in the enclosing web page.

Comment: I disabled the button as suggested. Thanks!

Comment: I learned jQuery watching Jeffrey Way videos and he always used the self-invoking anonymous function so that is what I use. Since I don't use other libraries which may compete for the dollar sign, do you think what I am doing in WRONG, NOT BEST PRACTICE, or just PERSONAL PREFERENCE? I ask because I would like to learn jQuery properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if( $('.overdraft').length > 0) {
    $('#btnSAMSubmit').hide();
}
```

Comment: Much more concise! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

At first sight, you're missing a `)`

```
if( $('tr').hasClass('overdraft')) // <-- This last ) is missed on your code
{
    $('#btnSAMSubmit').hide(); 
}
```

Comment: your first site is better than my 2,181st site. I will accept answer in 11 minutes.